# Row level security - Update Rows

Tags: postgresql, security, roles

Hi I am working with Postgres, I have one role  "my_role", and I want to update records from one table only where my corporate_id is related to other table.

I want to create a Policy to person table, and I have a corporate_id from my corporate table to drive to get this information would be something like these:

```
SELECT * FROM person p 
INNER JOIN person_brand a ON p.person_id=a.person_id 
INNER JOIN brand b ON a.brand_id=b.brand_id 
INNER JOIN corporate c on b.corporate_id=c.corporate_id
WHERE c.corporate_id=corporate_id
```

I my policy will be something like these:

```
ALTER TABLE core.person ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
CREATE POLICY person_corporation_all
    ON person
    AS PERMISSIVE
    FOR UPDATE
    TO "my_role"
    USING (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM person p 
                  INNER JOIN person_brand a ON p.person_id=a.person_id 
                  INNER JOIN brand b ON a.brand_id=b.brand_id 
                  INNER JOIN corporate c on b.corporate_id=c.corporate_id
                 WHERE c.corporate_id=corporate_id));
```

But show me this error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "corporate_id" is ambiguous
SQL state: 42702
```

What I need to send as variable into my query?

Regards

Comment: In both of your `WHERE` clauses, you have `c.corporate_id=corporate_id`, and it can't figure out which `corporate_id` you mean on the right side of the comparison. You need to alias it just like you've done in your `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a nested policy because inside the verification you have the `person` table again, you will need to remove it, and refers to the columns using the name of the table `person`, for example:

```
CREATE POLICY person_corporation_all
    ON person
    AS PERMISSIVE
    FOR UPDATE
    TO "my_role"
    USING (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM person_brand a 
                  INNER JOIN brand b ON a.brand_id=b.brand_id 
                  INNER JOIN corporate c on b.corporate_id=c.corporate_id
                 WHERE a.person_id=person.person_id and  c.corporate_id=person.corporate_id));
```